# PTC or One time Fuse or fusible resistor for li-ion protection.any suggestion?

Tags: lithium-ion, protection, fuses, ptc

I designing a kind of portable device ,it contains 450mAh Li_ion or Li_Poly Battery (depends on space on PCB).
I design this system for mass production (10k-20K).

[image]

I want to add overcurrent protection in my design because it uses  Li_ion or Li_Poly batteries and safety should consider.

There is no input on this circuit just some LED and 7 Segment (Kind of indicator system.) ,All of the system placed in Box and just Vin jack is Available.

Its very Rare situation that Overcurrent and short circuit happend ,but as this  is a portable device and i use battery ,i should consider(maybe battery charger IC fails and short circuit happend!)

The charger input(Vin) is always about 6.5V ,D1 used for input jack reverse protection.

the system power just came from battery and i use Boost DC-DC converter to power MCU and All other parts.(4.2 to 5 DC_DC conv wire.)

**Edit**
4.2 TO 5V DC-DC Converter is turned OFF when MCP73831 is turned ON.(when Vin is connected all the system is turned OFF and just battery charger works.)

My question is :

1-which of PTC or One time Fuse or fusible resistor is better for my design and why?

2-Is the fuse(F1) in the right place(series with battery)?

**Answer**:
After i Study some Application notes [here](https://m.littelfuse.com%20%E2%80%BA%20ec327-e_polyfuse_ptc) and [here](https://www.mpoweruk.com%20%E2%80%BA%20protection),I found out PCB mount PTC fuse is good option for my design.

Comment: Good/better **or** bad/worse = suitable for the product **or** not suitable for the product. You found PTC is better then you say **is it good for my design** and nobody here can see your design.

Comment: Your first question needs way more clarification as we don't know your design and specifications (specification as well! e.g. a PTC is likely not desired  when operating temperature ranges from -50°C to 100°C). Your second question is very broad and asks for general information that can be found by googling: (e.g. [Different Types of Fuses and Its Applications](https://www.elprocus.com/what-is-fuse-different-types-of-fuses-and-applications/)

Comment: @Andyaka ,Now i add full Description ,and add my deisgn.

Comment: The MCP73831 is a battery charger devoted to charging a battery and not supplying extra current (that it has no idea of) to an external load portrayed by the connection to a DC/DC converter. Additionally, it is unclear what the fuse is intended to do.

Comment: @Andyaka,I know this is just a battery charger and .i use the MCP73831just for charging the battery .when it charged .the system power came from battery (NOT MCP73831),i use DC-DC Converter becasue some part of my circuit is 5V.Here i want to add overcurrent and short circuit protection to my circuit ,and i want to use Fuse!

Comment: No, according to your schematic that charge current feeds a DC/DC converter.

Comment: @Andyaka ,it will not go there ,there is EN pin on my DC-DC converter , when Vin is conected, DC-DC converter is turned OFF and just circuit above is ON,there is no problem there

Comment: OK, that explains how you do your power switch management but, please explain what the fuse is intended to achieve. What does it protect and from what ?

Comment: @Andyaka.I have Edite on Schematic and add Text to clarify.The fuse will protect my circuit from over current and short circuit .I should consider the best safety for my design .